# How to display additional var value in jsp for loop

Tags: jsp, for-loop, jstl

I need the Page 2 inside the anchor tag to display dynamic number.  I can't use var "count" as it goes by 5 step.

```
<c:forEach var="count" begin="5" end="${postCount}" step="5">
      <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/switchPage?limit=5&offset=${count}">
          Page 2
      </a>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a varStatus attribute like this:

```
<c:forEach var="count" begin="5" end="${postCount}" step="5" varStatus="pageNum">
      <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/switchPage?limit=5&offset=${count}&page=${pageNum.index}">
          Page 2
      </a>
</c:forEach>
```

You can read more about it on the official [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_forEach.html).